# Запускать Android приложение из браузера

Tags: android, app

Чтобы запускать моё приложение из веб страницы должен ли попробовать online, или достаточна какой то запущенный html файл?

Comment: Опишите подробнее, как вы представляете запуск андроид-приложения из веб-страницы.

Comment: По идее можно даже просто через `adb` из командной строки интент в системе запустить и приложение может на него среагировать

Answer (score 0):

У Firebase появились [Dynamics Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/), которые позволяют открыть приложение, если оно установлено на устройстве, либо, например, отправить пользователя на страницу приложения в Google Play в случае, если оно не установлено на устройстве.

Возможно это то, что вам надо

Comment: Я хотел такого, когда нажимаю ссылку моё приложение должен запустить. Спасибо вам за ответы, у меня уже получилось.